# How to add preliminary message header to automatically forwarded emails in Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, forwarding

I have emails from one mailbox set up to be automatically forwarded to another. This is fine, but I'd like to add a tag to all of the forwarded emails that says:

"Begin forwarded message

------"

at the beginning.

Is this possible in Outlook? I can't seem to find anything online about it or anything in settings.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but only by using a VBA script.

You will need to create a rule for forwarding which runs a script
([link](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/outlooks-rules-and-alerts-run-a-script/)). The script will look something like this simple example
(totally untested) :

```
Sub SendNew(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim objMsg As MailItem
Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

objMsg.Subject = "FW: " & Item.Subject
objMsg.Body = "Begin forwarded message"  & Chr(10) & "------" & Chr(10) & Item.Body

objMsg.Send

End Sub
```

Some more work may be needed for HTML text.

See also [this article](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/send-a-new-message-when-a-message-arrives/).